# SQL Server 2008 displaying records horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the tables and data created in SqlFiddle( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72398/3)

I have 3 tables with data

`dbo.Contracts`:

```
C_ID,
C_NAME,
C_VOLUME
```

`dbo.Players`:

```
P_ID,
P_NAME
```

`dbo.ContractPlayers`:

```
C_ID,
P_ID,
Share
```

I am able to do simple joins which displays the data vertically. but i need the data horizontally

Like this:

```
C_ID | C_NAME       | C_Volume | P_NAME1  | SHARE1 | P_NAME2   | SHARE2 | P_NAME3 | SHARE3 |
 1   | Agriculture  |  40000   | Johndeer |  3000  | Statefarm | 4500   | Vortex  | 3200   | 
 2   | Chemicals    |  50000   | Johndeer |  1231  | Statefarm | 2345   | Vortex  | 2311   | 
 3   | Autos        |  35000   | Johndeer |  1212  | Statefarm | 1111   | Vortex  | 4534   |
```

I am assuming this is possible. Please help Here is the sqlFiddle( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72398/3)

Comment: Take a look at `PIVOT`

Comment: Is the number of columns always going to be the same, or will it vary?

Comment: The players may add in future so no of columns may not be same.

Comment: I would suggest fetch data the way you are doing now, and manipulate it in your programming language